# How to use SweetAlert messages for validation in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, sweetalert, laravel-8, laravel-validation

I'm using Laravel to develop my project, and I want to return a SweetAlert error message when the user DOES NOT MARK the Recaptcha. I coded this in `LoginController.php`:

```
use App\Providers\SweetAlertServiceProvider;

protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        $this->username() => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => ['required' , new Recaptcha]
    ],[
        'g-recaptcha-response.required' => alert()
        ->error('Bad','Attempt')->persistent('Ok')
    ]);
}
```

Instead of showing an alert, it returns the following message.

> Error Object of class UxWeb\SweetAlert\SweetAlertNotifier could not be
> converted to string

However, I have already added this line to `config/app.php` in the provider's section.

```
UxWeb\SweetAlert\SweetAlertServiceProvider::class
```

So what's going wrong here? What else should I have done to return this alert message?

Comment: Have you tried using `composer dump-autoload` to clear the Autoload Cache?

Comment: Yes, I did already, but not useful

Comment: You can not do that my friend, since validation returns text but that alert you wanna use is returning a file session!

Answer (score 1):

You can use manual validation to return something other than a string :

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'username' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'password' => 'required',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => ['required' , new Recaptcha]
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        if($validator->errors()->has('g-recaptcha-response'))
            SweetAlert::error('please validate the captcha, thanks !')
        return redirect()
                    ->back()
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    }
```

also make sure you have installed and included sweetalert in your code :

installation :

```
composer require uxweb/sweet-alert
```

in your controller :

```
use SweetAlert;
```

in your blade view :

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Include this in your blade layout -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        @include('sweet::alert')
    </body>
</html>
```

references :

[laravel docs (1)](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#manually-creating-validators)
[uxweb/sweet-alert repo (2)](https://github.com/uxweb/sweet-alert)

Comment: Now I get `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\SweetAlert' not found` error

Comment: @fojbiu add `use SweetAlert;` to your controller.

Comment: Hello before trying to use sweet alert try to install it got to your App root director and run on cmd / terminal  composer require SweetAlert

Comment: I have installed Sweet Alert package with Composer, I included `<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>` at the the head section of `app.blade.php` and also added `@yield('form')` in the body section of this page. Then I included it at my blade correctly. After that I did what you said at your answer. But still get this error: `Class 'SweetAlert' not found` :(((

Comment: @fojbiu Did you add `use SweetAlert;` to your controller ? it must be added or your controller won't be able to find the class. read the usage carefully please : [link](https://github.com/uxweb/sweet-alert#usage)
you can also find there many ways to achieve what you want to do